# Can I add the required attribute to an input field using css?

Tags: html, recaptcha, required-field

I have a recaptcha widget in my form and i want it to be made mandatory.
since i dont have any direct control over the widget in my html, i was wondering if i can add the required attribute to it after it has been rendered.

ie. if i add the folloing css

```
#recaptcha_response_field{background-color:#000000;}
```

it does color up the recaptcha widget text field. in the same vein, if there was some way of setting the required="required" attribute for input fields via css, i'd be able to make it mandatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the following work for you:

```
$(function() {
    $("#recaptcha_response_field").attr('required','required');
});
```

Comment: unfortunately, no. i added it to my js file but it had no effect.

Comment: got it to work after removing the function tags.

$("#recaptcha_response_field").attr('required','required');

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this should do the trick:

```
$(function() {
    $("#recaptcha_response_field").css({background-color:#000000;});
});
```

Without jQuery:

```
document.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("recaptcha_response_field").style['background-color'] = '#000000';
};
```

I'm not 100% sure on the second one, but I can't test it right now.

Comment: i think you misunderstood me. i wanted to put the attribute "required" on the field.
I gave an example where i can put in the style on the field. I just wanted to know if it was possible to put in the required attribute in a similar way.